# How to use jQuery in flash

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, flash

That's my AS3

```
bbt1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_10);
function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_10(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(ExternalInterface.available)
    {       
    ExternalInterface.call('hid');
    }

}
```

and that's my jQuery

```
function hid()
{
    $('#hid7').toggle('blind');
}
```

and my html

```
<div style="display:none; " id="hid7">

 <object width="650" height="500" style="border:solid 1px; ">
      <param name="movie" value="Kulon/variant6.swf"></parm>


                   </embed>
                </object>

                </div>
```

On the stage i have bbt and i want when i click on the btn to activate the hid function

Comment: `</parm>` and `</embed>` look suspicious. Are they mistypes?

Comment: well it's not working again

Comment: Is the hid function called? Try sticking a breakpoint or a log statement in and you can rule out a problem with your jquery.

Comment: i am a begginer can you help me with the breakpoint or the log statement